# How do I cast my Android phone's display onto a large screen in real-time?

Tags: screencast

Is it possible to cast the screen of an Android phone onto a large display screen while playing a game on it so that every action and move of the person playing the game shows on the screen in real time?

What I want is that the gamer plays the game while looking at the phone and touching the phone screen only but a large number of people are able to see his game in **real-time** on the large screen.

Comment: Why not Chromecast or Miracast?

Comment: Check out NITROME TOUCHEY...http://www.nitrome.com/touchy/

Comment: Please update your question with the phone and OS version

Comment: @Lucky I am asking possibility. Is it possible in general?

Comment: Yes it is possible using chromecast or Miracast feature as george suggested. But not all phones have this feature to cast their screen onto a bigger screen. So it depends on the device capabilties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using an Amazing app called [Shou](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.shou.android&hl=en). You can record, broadcast, and mirror your device screen.

As about mirroring, real time mirroring is available, to view on any device with a browser.